# Sagemaker Studio errors a loading screen to clear workspace every-time when connected "open studio"

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

On resuming or restarting the sagemaker-studio I have the below message pop-up.

[image: Sagemaker-Studio Loading.. clear workspace error screen]

Even after clearing the workspace, it won't open. After few such retries, the Jupiter notebook (sagemaker studio / IDE) opens. I get this message every time I reconnect and approx 15 mins are wasted each time :(

Am I doing something wrong while stopping/closing the sagemaker studio?

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that when I get this issue, in my case, it's due to a Jupyter server that I left open, and something in the connection with GitLab goes wrong after a certain time (I haven't been able to understand why exactly).

If you go to "Domains" > your user profile, you'll see that there is a `default` app, the one that holds the Jupyter server, and others that hold the kernels.

I usually save my changes, then delete the `default` app. Then I login again in my SageMaker Studio profile, which automatically recreates the `default` app. This solves the login issue for some time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart the Jupyter Server Studio application. On the AWS management console, you can go to SageMaker / Studio, select your user profile and click on the **Delete app** button next to the Jupyter Server application.

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if your Subnets are Public or Private. Apparently Sagemaker Notebooks use NAT gateway and not IGW gateway.